# Broken ... System Image for Android in SDK Manager

Tags: android

I notice the following in my Android SDK Manager (capture below):

```
Broken Intel x86 Atom System Image, API 16
Broken Mips System Image, API 16
Broken ARM EABI v7a System Image, API 16
```

Where should I store my System Image for the above in which folder inside android-sdk to get rid of the "Broken" error message?

---

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I realize that actually, I need to have the API 16 in my SDK manager, otherwise, the system images will broken.

Comment: How did u Recover the system images

Comment: @madanV there is nothing to recover, because the system image itself is not broken, it's just that the SDK Manager can't recognise it because it doesn't have that API installed (no corresponding folder under "platforms/" to match the one under "system-images/")

Answer (score 3):

you have to install "Google play services for fit Preview"
it's work for me
[image]